# Lwip tcp_write payload pbuf gives inconsistent values using memcpy

Tags: c, tcp, memcpy, lwip

I'm working on a TCP/IP configuration using the lwip library.

I'm trying to send a "Hello" char buffer using the pbuf structure and memcpy function. However, it gives me inconsistent results.

When I listen to the port from [Wireshark](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wireshark) (option 1), "Hello" is already located in the payload. However, it is located at the middle of the payload, e.g. (not starting from array[0] element). It is starting around the 40th element of the char array, and before that the "Hello" value there are some junk values also.

```
struct pbuf *p;
char msg[400] = "Hello";

// Option 1: Gives me Hello with junk value
p = pbuf_alloc(PBUF_TRANSPORT, 400, PBUF_POOL);
if (!p)
{
   xil_printf("Error while allocating pbuf \n\r");
}

memcpy(p->payload, msg, 400);
err = tcp_write(pcb, p, p-> len, 1);

// Option 2: It's OK
err = tcp_write(pcb, "Hello\n\r", strlen("Hello\n\r"), 1);
```

I can use option 2 for my application. However, I want to now do this with option 1 also.

Comment: Unrelated to your problem, but the newline sequence is usually `"\r\n"`, opposite of what you're having. Some systems and environments might not be able to handle it your way.

Comment: Thank you, i will try it for option 2, however i am mainly trying to understand proper way for option 1.

Comment: As for your "problem", the [IP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IPv4) header is typically 20 bytes, followed by a 20 byte [TCP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transmission_Control_Protocol) header. Perhaps this is the reason your data starts at byte 40? You look at the IP and TCP headers as well?

Comment: No unfortunately, it is after the ethernet and ip section, it is exactly on the tcp data section. Also headers are ok.

Comment: Well we can't see what Wireshark is showing you so the only thing we can guess is that you look at the raw package including IP and TCP headers. And since those are 40 bytes and your data starts "around" byte 40 it seems to fit.

Comment: What happens in the receiving program by the way? How does it receive the data? Does it receive the data correctly?

Comment: i wrote it arbitrarily like middle of somewhere of array, now i count it it starts at 129th byte, also after "hello" data array is empty as we want. again it is not about headers, tcp connection is proper, problem is about tcp_write. For the receiver program, yes with the garbage value.

Comment: Perhaps the problem is that you write the `pbuf` structure itself instead of its payload? Try using `p->payload` instead. Or why use the `pbuf` structure at all? Why not `tcp_write(pdb, msg, sizeof msg /* or perhaps strlen(msg) */, 1)`?

Comment: i will use constructing pbuf structure from scratch, of course strlen option is suitable.

Comment: As @Someprogrammerdude already suggested, option 1 might not be what you want. The first field of pbuf struct is a pointer to the "next" pbuf struct and the address of this latter is likely what you are passing to the tcp_write. Instead, it looks tcp_write expects a TCP payload buffer. Notice also that tcp_write performs pbuf allocation itself and then copies your input payload buffer into it.